# Form action doesn't work | Django

Tags: django, forms, exception

Hi i made some ModelForm. now when i enter i got this Error.

```
RuntimeError
Exception Value:    

You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/comp/new/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

What is causing this? May form action matches exactly the form URL comp/new and this match to my view to render and work with the data. But something went wrong....

My Url

```
url(r'^comp/new/$', 'company.views.add_company', name='add_company'),
```

My Form action

```
<form id="category_form" method="post" action="/comp/new/">
```

Comment: It needs a / on the end. Your form action obviously doesn't have one, as even you say in your post. /comp/new/ - the error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: i tried to put the slash like this /comp/new/ on it but not working. Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/comp/new   its not changing.

Comment: Show us your form code - the HTML for it.

Comment: Could you post your view as well? And change your form template to this: `<form id="category_form" method="post" action="{% url 'add_company' %}">`

Comment: its working now. it was the backslash on the action. browser dont reloaded new html. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Probably your are using `reverse` so check your urls.py, the missing / should be there